# CSS style is working in parent stylesheet, but not in child

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

I'm building a website and have run into a CSS issue. I'm using Bootstrap 3, but I also have two additional custom stylesheets. I have an image banner, which I'd like to apply some top padding to in a page that uses both stylesheets (parent linked before child). For some reason when I write the style in the child sheet, it isn't applied, but when I add it to the parent it works. I'd like to have it in the child, for the sake of keeping everything organized, but I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this.

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="middle-wrap" class="row">

        <div id="about-header">

            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/banners/about-banner.png">

        </div>
```

Child CSS (for about.html)

```
/*-------About Header----------*/
#about-header       { padding-top:15px; }
/*-----------------------------*/
```

linking in about.html

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- additional custom styles -->
<link href="css/about.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- additional custom styles -->
```

EDIT:

Hey, thanks for the replies. First, I'm not sure what exactly you mean by a path change @NKL, as in just moving the stylesheet to a different directory? Also, I tried marking it as '!important' but that didn't seem to do anything. The funny thing is when the style is in the child sheet, and I inspect the element in chrome, the style is nowhere to be found, and I can't seem to find a style there that would be overriding it. But when I move the style to the parent sheet, and inspect the element, it shows right up. This makes me think that there's something the parent sheet that's overriding the style, but I can't figure out what--there's nothing in there with the same name or target.

Comment: Have you tried considering a path change? i.e `../` ??

Comment: Have you tried using inspect element to check if it's not just being overriden by a selector with higher specificity?

Comment: In previous linked files is probably stronger selector like `#page #about-header {padding-top: 0;}` which isn't overwritten by this rule.

Comment: Try to increase specificity with something like this `.container #middle-wrap #about-header`

Comment: @GermanoPlebani hey, thanks, but it doesn't seem to be a specificity problem--I've tried everything up to "body .container #middle-wrap #about-header img" with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing it. I had an HTML comment in my child css sheet (see below) and it was negating the first style under it. Obviously I just changed it to CSS comments (/* */), and the problem was solved. Thanks everyone for your input, it definitely sped up the diagnosis.

```
<!-- Remember-anything written here will OVERRIDE the styles
already extracted from index.css, so add only what you
need, be it new styles, or overrides -->
```

Comment: Good! HTML comment in CSS works only with old browser :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
#about-header {
  padding-top: 15px !important;
}
```

It seems like your custom CSS for `#about-header` will be overridden by some of your styles or bootstrap.min.css style. Your style will be used if you use `! important`

Comment: it seems like your custom css for #about-header will be overridden by some of your styles or bootstrap.min.css style. Your style will be used if you use "important".

Comment: erk - you should avoid using !important to solve CSS issues. Only use it if you absolutely must, or if it is genuinely appropriate. This will be a simple case of css priority. Making the css class more specific will sort this out.